# Как сделать callback на callback получив данные от пользователя?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Как после `async def get_command(callback: types.callback_query)` реализовать другую callback функцию, в которой бот будет отправлять текст "Введите количество BTC или USDT (в зависимости от нажатой кнопки), запоминать данные, которые отправил пользователь?

```
import logging
import ccxt
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

API_TOKEN = ''

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
CryptoBot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(CryptoBot)

we = ccxt.wavesexchange({
    'api_key': ' ',
    'secret': 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY',
})


# ib_btc = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обменять BTC на USDT')
# ib_usdt = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обменять USDT на BTC')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    ib = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Получить', callback_data="Получить")
    ikb.add(ib)
    await CryptoBot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                                 text=f'{message.from_user.first_name}, приветствую! Я CryptoBot!\nЯ умею получать текущий курс BTC/USDT по нажатию кнопки "Получить", а при нажатии кнопки "Обменять BTC на USDT" или "Обменять USDT на BTC" могу рассчитать стоимость и перейти к оплате!',
                                 reply_markup=ikb)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def get_command(callback: types.callback_query):
    kbft = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    ib_btc = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обменять BTC на USDT',callback_data="Обменять BTC")
    ib_usdt = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обменять USDT на BTC',callback_data="Обменять USDT")
    kbft.add(ib_btc, ib_usdt)
    if callback.data == "Получить":
        we.load_markets()
        currencies = we.currencies
        symbols = we.symbols
        waves_usdn = we.markets['BTC-WXG/USDC-WXG']
        info = waves_usdn["info"]
        high = info['24h_high']
        low = info['24h_low']
        vwap = info['24h_vwap']
        opened = info['24h_open']
        closed = info['24h_close']
        value = f"Максимальная цена:\n{high} USDT \nМинимальная цена:\n{low} USDT \nСредневзвешенная цена:\n{vwap} USDT \nЦена открытия:\n{opened} USDT \nЦена последней сделки:\n{closed} USDT"
        return await callback.message.answer(value, reply_markup=kbft)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```